# Bookdown and rendering kable tables to a word document

Tags: r, ms-word, knitr, bookdown, kableextra

I am trying to generate a Word document from a `bookdown` file. All seems to work well, apart from the last chunk where I'm attempting to knit a kable table. There seems to be a problem generating tables that run over a page. If I try to render:

```
library(kableExtra)
tab <- bind_rows(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars)
kableExtra::kable(tab) %>% 
      kable_styling(full_width = T, font_size = 12) %>%
      column_spec(1, bold = T)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Functions that produce HTML output found in document targeting docx output.
Please change the output type of this document to HTML. Alternatively, you can allow
HTML output in non-HTML formats by adding this option to the YAML front-matter of
your rmarkdown file:

  always_allow_html: true
```

My `yaml` config is as follows:

```
# Config parametres for word rendering      
bookdown::word_document2:
  split_by: chapter
  toc: yes
  toc_depth: 3
```

If I add `always_allow_html: true` I still get the same error.

Comment: In rmd file, this line `bind_rows(mtcars,mtcars,mtcars) %>% knitr::kable()
` works fine and outputs docx, no issues. Please provide reproducible setup.

Comment: You're right. Sorry about that. The problem seems to be with `kableExtra`. I have updated my question.

Comment: No worries, I recently faced the same issue, and ended up using just knitr::kable, instead of kableextra.

Comment: so `KableExtra` doesn't seem to play nicely with bookdown when a table covers more than one page?

Comment: I don't think kableExtra works for Word output. It mainly works for HTML and LaTeX: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/kableextra.html